# "not all code paths return a value" error in a bool type function

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a function that receives an array and check that the array size is an odd number and that all the numbers preceding the middle index are bigger than it and all that follows are smaller and if so return true. I wrote the function but it keeps giving me this error.
this is my code:

thanks in advance.

```
static bool Balance(int[] array)
{
    int count = 0, middle;
    bool check = true;
    foreach (int item in array)
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0)
        check = false;
    else
    {
        middle = array.Length / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < middle)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[middle])
                {
                    check = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(i > middle)
                if(array[i] > array[middle])
                {
                    check = false;
                }
        }
    }
    if (check == false)
        return false;
    if (check == true)
        return true;
```

Comment: `if (check == false) return false; if (check == true) return true;` - why no `if-else`? or just an even simpler `return check`? you already have a boolean to return at this point.

Comment: I tried just switching to return check but still the same error.

Comment: From a human standpoint, it's clear that `check` can only ever be `true` or `false`, and that you're satisfying the requirement to return a value. The compiler doesn't make that assumption though, so you need `if (check) { return true; } else { return false; }` so that every perceived possible branch is accounted for. Though, as Franz says, just return `check` and remove the conditional logic altogether.

Comment: Some notes on your code: Counting the element in the array is useless. There is already a property named _array.Length_ or the IEnumerable extension _array.Count()_. When you discover an entry to be false you could _break_ the loop. No need to check other items, you have already decided the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler isn't as smart as you might think.

It doesn't know that the two last if cases covers all cases.

Switch to:

```
        if (check == false)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
```

And it will work!

Or just simplify:

```
return check;
```

Comment: the First one worked thanks!, also I should note that I did tried the return check before and still same issue.

Comment: @maor It's not possible for `return check;` to exhibit the same behaviour in that position, unless you're doing `if (check == false) { return check; } else if (check == true) { return check; }`, which would be very redundant.

Answer (score 1):

When you write a method with a return type specified, make sure your code returns a value.

```
static  bool Balance(int[] array)
{
    int count = 0, middle;
    bool check = true;
    foreach (int item in array)
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0)
        check = false;
    else
    {
        middle = array.Length / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < middle)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[middle])
                {
                    check = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(i > middle)
                if(array[i] > array[middle])
                {
                    check = false;
                }
        }
    }
    return check; // since you are checking the value in two `if` blocks, it would raise the error because compiler doesn't see the else part where the code flow will certainly go. this is the cleanest way in your code to return the value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because compiler doesn´t know logic about your code and every path of your code needs to return a value.

In your case your simply can return the value of variable "check" at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

change the last `if` to `else` and remove `(check == true)`
or just add 1 more line of code to your function
`return false;`

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurred because in the end of your code you are using only if condition, you haven't returned any value for else condition.

```
if (check == false)
     return false;
if (check == true)
     return true;
```

You should write it in this way,

```
if(check == false)
{
   return false;
}else return true;
```

Or simply you can just return the "check" variable as you are ultimately just returning the true value of this variable,

```
return check;
```